# running multiple threads with continous value returns (ping program)

Tags: c#, multithreading, ping

good day

I have taken up a project that as a bases needs insernt a command into cmd "ping x.x.x.x -t" and the program needs to return the output until a specified parameter

I am considering threads as my unterstanding in multithreading is limited, I am unable to continue without guidance

my ping class which recieves a string ip, adds it to a precompiled command string, etc.

I am aware of the built in ping class for this use, but I would prefer the "longer" method since i would gain valueble information/experience from this

main object class: **ping**

```
class ping
{
    Process proc;
    ProcessStartInfo psi;
    string ip_address;
    bool bStop = false;        

    public ping(string ip)
    {
        ip_address = ip;
    }

    public void StartPing()
    {
        string cmdInput;
        psi = new ProcessStartInfo(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMSPEC"));
        psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc = Process.Start(psi);

        proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("ping " + ip_address + " -t");        

        cmdInput = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        cmdInput = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        cmdInput = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        cmdInput = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        cmdInput = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        cmdInput = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        while (bStop == false)
        {
            cmdInput = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(returnPing(cmdInput));
        }
        proc.Close();
    }

    private string returnPing(string cmdInput)
    {
        int start, end;
        string ping;
        if (cmdInput.IndexOf("Reply") != -1 && cmdInput.IndexOf("time") != -1)
        {
            start = cmdInput.IndexOf("time=") + 5;
            end = cmdInput.IndexOf("ms");
            ping = cmdInput.Substring(start, end - start);
            return ping;

        }
        else return "-1";
    }
```

and **thread_handler** class, which manages mutliple instances of the ping method, please not the console.writeline is a temporary output which I will change in the future

```
class thread_handler
{
    string[] ipList;
    private IList<Thread> threadList;

    public thread_handler(string[] ip)
    {
        ipList = ip;
        threadList = new List<Thread>();
        createThreads();            
    }

    private void createThreads()
    {
        foreach (string item in ipList)
        {
            ping NewPing = new ping(item);
            Thread newPingThread = new Thread(NewPing.StartPing);
            newPingThread.IsBackground = true;
            newPingThread.Name = string.Format("{0}", item);
            threadList.Add(newPingThread);
        }
        startAllThreads();
    }

    private void startAllThreads()
    {
        foreach (Thread item in threadList)
        {
            item.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

**Program**

```
class Program
{
    static string[] ipList;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ipList = new String[3];
        readData();
        sendData();       
    }

    private static void sendData()
    {
        thread_handler thIp = new thread_handler(ipList);
    }

    private static void readData()
    {
        //use sll with name defintions and ip address's with metadata
        ipList[0] = "10.0.0.2";
        ipList[1] = "telkom_exchange";
        ipList[2] = "goo.gl";

    }
```

The aim of this program is (with gui changes in future) for a simple console with respective dimensions to constantly ping certain ip address's (we have ban infrastructure, thus program is for informative purposes), constantly updating on every ping reply

I do not want anyone to finish this program, I simply require assistance with running multiple instances (or maybe "threads") of this pinging, thus

**each thread as it runs the "StartPing()" method, it should return an output, e.g. simply output the ping into the console, but it doesnt...**

Output:

```
 The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe. 
 The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
```

then hangs

Comment: There are some basic issues in the code you posted -- setting the threads as background will cause the whole program to terminate prematurely, and you're not extracting the correct substring from the ping process output -- but otherwise it works as expected when I run it. I certainly don't see any "...write to a nonexistent pipe" message. You need to double-check your code example to make sure that what you post here reproduces the problem.

Comment: Also, you should break the problem into smaller pieces, so that you can ask a more specific question. I.e. if you need help with `Process`, don't provide a code example that also involves the `ping` command. Write a code example that reproduces the issue without that.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I thank you for your response, my good sir, the issue was with the backround parameter, i had to set it to false, that solved my problem completely, by any chance, could you assist with/point me in the right direction: accessing/modifing the onExit method of a console application, i.e. I want to terminate all threads before closing, a long way to do a simple thing, but this is for imformation purposes, all links I visited gave me a whole controlset rewrite methods, etc. which I doubt is the best way for this

Comment: @PeterDuniho in regards to the second comment, how I ask a question is providing all relevant information about the problem and the context, I understand that it might confuse the actual problem but rather to much info than lacking, but I will keep this in mind in future

Comment: There is no _"onExit method"_. The closest thing to that would be [`AppDomain.ProcessExit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit(v=vs.110).aspx) event. But it's better if you simply synchronize your threads, using one of several available mechanisms in .NET for the purpose. Your main thread can signal the background threads to clean up and exit, then wait for them to do so. That's a whole other question, and you should research the specifics before asking something so broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you read from the child process is not right. This is a surprisingly complicated task. I don't know why you are getting this specific error message but it sounds like it has to do with process standard output redirection. For example you have not redirected standard error.

I suggest you use one of the top voted snippets of stack overflow, to be found by: `site:stackoverflow.com process RedirectStandardOutput`. There are hundreds of such questions. Most solutions are subtly wrong.

[This is a good checklist.](http://csharptest.net/321/how-to-use-systemdiagnosticsprocess-correctly/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [ping class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to execute a ping. This class allows you to control many details.

The call to `ping.exe` with `Process.Start()` involves way too much overhead and complicates things (as you experienced in your try)

Comment: thank you but i did specify, and i will say again "I am aware of the built in ping class for this use, but I would prefer the "longer" method since i would gain valueble information/experience from this"

Answer (score 0):

As simple as it is, redirecting standard input and output did it, with a tweak or two, voila